# SEO - folder or file

Tags: seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I use a file extension or not?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3079/should-i-use-a-file-extension-or-not)

I'm creating a website with a number of pricing options. Each price plan has it's own page and there is also a comparison page. As far as SEO is concerned, which of the following is better? or does it not make a difference?

**Option one - folders**

> /pricing/plans
>
> /pricing/plans/free

**Option two- files**

> /pricing/plans.php
>
> /pricing/free-plan.php

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would advocate using the first option, because it reveals the structure and hierachy of your site, while the second options shows basically two unrelated URI.

Aside from that, I am afraid I don't have any reference on which to base this, but generally, I think the structure of your site should be self-explanatory, and thus the first option is better imo.