# SEO - File naming

Tags: filenames

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I use hyphens or underscores?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/374/should-i-use-hyphens-or-underscores)

Hi
For the file name "mission-and-vision.htm" or "mission_and_vision.htm", which one is good for SEO(separator "-" or "_")?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hyphens are the recommended separator - Google doesn't treat the _ as a word separator, so to count it would have to be the literal string:  "mission_and_vision" that was searched for.

See [Matt Cutts on this in 2005](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/dashes-vs-underscores/)